# Definite integral - taking a constant term out added a power to it

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

We have $\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-\lambda x}dx$ = $\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{-y}dy $
[Set $y=\lambda x$]

I have been so confused about the $\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$ term. Shouldn't it just be $\frac{1}{\lambda}$?

Because setting $y=\lambda x$, we have:

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{y}{\lambda}e^{-y}dy $.

Taking the constant term $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ out, which would now give:

$\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{-y}dy $

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You're forgetting that $dx=\frac{1}{\lambda}dy$.

Comment: thank you for the answer! it helped a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y=\lambda x$, then $dy=\lambda dx$ so you have $$\int_0^{\infty}xe^{-\lambda x}dx=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{y}{\lambda}e^{-y}\left(\frac{dy}{\lambda}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

If you note that $\mathrm{d}y = \lambda\mathrm{d}x$, you will get the right answer